# Pointer to member function-object in std::invoke

Tags: c++, c++17

Why std::invoke does not work with a pointer to member which is a function object with arguments? Like this:

```
struct MyClass
{
    std::function<void(int)> functor{ [](int arg) { printf("%d\n", arg); } };
};
int main()
{
    MyClass mc;
    std::invoke(&MyClass::functor, mc, 110);
}
```

Prints : `'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found.`
I checked this in Visual C++ and g++.

Moreover, `std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&MyClass::functor), MyClass, int>` claims that this functor is not invocable, which is definitely wrong.
Am I missing something or it is a defect in the standard? If this behavior is correct, then what is the point in std::invoke and all its friends? What I mean is that simple function objects can be easily called without any facilities, but I though the main purpose of std::invoke is to generalize and simplify working with all callables, including the tricky ones, like pointers to members. The fact that std::invoke cannot invoke a clearly invocable target seems weird to me.

Comment: You meant `std::invoke(mc.functor, 110);`?

Comment: No! Because in this case it would invoke functor as it is, not as a pointer to member. What if you have a pointer to member and want to call it on different objects? Just like it works with pointers to member functions.

Comment: There is no pointer-to-member here. Only a `std::function` and it can only be invoked with 1 argument, an `int`.

Comment: @super `&MyClass::functor` is a pointer to member.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `functor` is not a function, but a data member. As such, `&MyClass::functor` is not a pointer to member function, but a pointer to member data. This distinction means that you cannot pass any other arguments to `std::invoke`, as you cannot call a data member; but for some data members, like your `functor` you can. The standard is not clear on this before C++11, and so there was [LWG issue 1520](https://wg21.link/lwg1520) which got merged in C++11.

I mean you can rewrite your example as:

```
std::invoke(&MyClass::functor, mc)(110);
// or for maximum confusion
std::invoke(std::invoke(&MyClass::functor, mc), 110);
```

but I don't think that's what you want. [Thanks to Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry), this is a bad idea, as what would the following code do:

```
struct X {
  std::function<void()> f;
};
std::invoke(&X::f, x); // gets f, or calls f?
```

Getting `f` would make it consistent with other data members, but then you have no way of invoking `f` if `f` takes no arguments. Calling `f` means that you get an inconsistency with other data members when you just want to get them.

Comment: This should be allowed? Really? Seems like it causes more confusion to me. I'm pretty sure the issue is proposing to make it ill-formed.

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah, I'm also not so sure, I just think it might be useful and also in terms of consistency (if a pointer-to-function can be invoked, so should a "pointer-to-functor").

Comment: The problem with allowing it is: what does this do `struct X { function<void()> f; }; std::invoke(&X::f, some_x)` Does that (a) mean `some_x.f` or (b) mean `some_x.f()`?

Comment: @Barry yikes, that's horrible. Both answers make sense, and both of them have really dumb shortcomings. Thanks for bringing this up :)

Comment: Well it like... _has_ to be (a). But then, you end up with this weird hole where if you had a `function<void(int)>`, you can invoke through, but if it doesn't take arguments, you can't? Easier to just have a model where pointer-to-member-data is a function that takes one argument that is class type and returns that member.

Comment: LWG issue 1520 was fixed before C++11 was published. The standard is clear.

Comment: @cpplearner Huh, how did I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out!